# Javascript undefined, truthy vs typeof operator

Tags: javascript, typeof, referenceerror

Considering the following code:

```
//the var Test has NOT been declared yet

console.log((typeof Test)); // "undefined"
console.log(Test); //"Uncaught ReferenceError: Test is not defined"
```

Why does the second console.log statement throw a ReferenceError and the first displays undefined.

Comment: Because the variable isn't defined. Where's the question in this?

Comment: This is worth a read for you: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/understanding-undefined-and-preventing-referenceerrors/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because test is undefined.

In that first `console.log` you're asking the system to tell you the type of a variable. So it looks through the current scope chain to find a reference to that variable so it may infer its type.

When it doesn't find the variable, it receives the `undefined` primitive. Which has a type, as I'm sure you've guessed, of `undefined`.

The second time you're asking it to print out the value of an undefined variable. Since the variable is not defined (there is no reference to it in the current scope chain), this is an error you're trying to ACCESS DATA that doesn't exist, not just infer its type.

Comment: Thanks. However, why does this not throw a ref error. var d = d || {} ?

Comment: [Variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)! When you say `var d`, regardless of where in you do it, at the start of the scope it defines `d` and sets it equal to `undefined`. So by the time you get to assigning it to itself, it's defined as a variable but it's **value** is `undefined`. Since `undefined` is "falsy", the interpreter moves to the next clause and since it's "truthy", sets d to the object literal.

Comment: Put `function test(){console.log(d); var d = 'test';}; a()` in your JS interpreter. It'll print out 'undefined" in the `console.log` statement, even though I'm not "declaring" `d` until the next line.